# Can i share my app with OLEDB 12.0?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

How can i share my app to my friends and they do not have to install anything, i try it, but 
[error when they launch the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKl8M.png)

I have to add any dll or what?

Answer (score 0):

The ACE provider needs a driver that usually comes with Microsoft Access:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Depending on the type of file that you are reading, you can use different provider instead. For example, for .mdb and .xls files:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: Further to this, all the new file formats introduced with Office 2003 (ACCDB, XLSX, etc.) require the ACE database engine.  All old file formats are supported by ACE but also by Jet, which is essentially a Windows component these days. If you're not using any new Office features, which is unlikely if you're not creating an application in Access, then you will not lose anything by using an MDB file instead of an ACCDB file.  You can also use a SQLite database, which can be accessed simply with a DLL that doesn't require separate installation.